# Unable to deploy contracts on devnet, is there anyone facing same issue? Anything issue network?

Tags: solana-program, devnet

0.0% | Waiting for next block, 107 pending...   [block height 163390010; re-sign in 202 blocks]

Comment: delete the ```target``` folder. rebuild and deploy. Don't forget to update the program id in ```declare_id()``` and ```anchor.toml``` file. This might work.

Comment: update your solana-cli version

Comment: I am facing the same problem. It may be a problem of devnet RPC but I am not sure. After type `solana program deploy ./target/deploy/hello_world.so` I had the same issue on waiting for next block...

Answer (score 1):

This was solved for me updating to the latest `solana-cli` version to 1.14